# Trojan virus threat 'removed or restored'

Tags: windows, virus, malware, windows-defender, trojan

I recently downloaded a file from a malicious website by mistake. It had a trojan virus with the name as following :-
Trojan.win32.Zapchast
My windows defender detected the threat and then quarantined it, I went to my threat protection history and then clicked on remove threat.
Subsequently, when I open the threat protection history, the windows defender says that "the threat has been removed OR restored". I am unable to understand the meaning of the word restored. Has the Virus been removed or restored?
I ran multiple scans from Windows defender and it does not defect any threats. I ran scans from Malware Fox, Malwarebytes and they haven't detected anything either. I am genuinely very scared. Can someone please tell me whether it would have been removed or is it still there? Should I call Dell Service provider?

Answer (score 2):

It means that it was removed from the quarantine area. Nothing more and nothing less.

For whatever reason the database they use to keep track of things apparently *only* tracks whether it is in quarantine or not. If it in quarantine then it is happy, if it is not in quarantine then either you removed it, or you restored it assuming you knew it was a false positive or accepted the risk.

If you know you clicked "remove" then all is fine, it is simply gone.

Comment: I am pretty sure I clicked remove and since I have run full scans by quick heal and windows defender, can I be assured that there is no virus actually left?

Comment: Chances are you are fine. The message is just vague, not actively dangerous.

Comment: I just want to ask one more question. Let's say I accidentally clicked restore the quarantine file( a hypothetical scenario). If I run a Windows defender Scan, will it it detect this threat this time around?

Comment: Should I get my laptop formatted and OS reinstalled again

Comment: I don't think you need to reformat unless you really doubt what you did and think your machine is now infected. If you "restored" the file it should be back where it was originally downloaded and might end up being "whitelisted" so that it does not get removed again. I would expect a scan of the directory *should* show it again, but might  not actually delete it.

Comment: I'm sure that i clicked on remove but I'm basically very paranoid right now, because I have encountered such a situation for the first time. Will reformatting ensure that every virus has been removed? If yes, then I guess I'll reformat it. please tell me if you know